# Is Flink job manager stateful or stateless?

Tags: apache-flink

Let's say all nodes that are running Flink job manager are restarted at the same time, is there any impact to the running task managers which are untouched?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The new job managers will restart all of the jobs from their latest checkpoints, using the information (job graphs, checkpoint metadata) they find in the HA service provider.